# online HTML editor how to store images

Tags: html, editor, photo

I am working with iPad and using some random HTML online editor. I explain to my pupils HTML coding and how to include photos on a webpage. How do I store images for my webpage and what is the path in my HTML code if I am working in online editor? Is it still possible to display images or it cannot be done in online editor but it has be done with the use of HTML coding programs installed on a computer?

Answer (score 0):

You can display images. Make sure you have the image in a directory in the editor or as the same directory as your main HTML file in.

Comment: What I meant when wrote an online editor was the website that would allow me to write some code, run it and see results. How do i then have a directory if it is a coding website ?

Comment: Use another online editor. I recommend [replit](https://replit.com)